# Android < 21: Animated vector flickering when using elliptical arc "A" sign

Tags: android, svg, vector

When I draw a vector graphic with a elliptical arc "A" sign on a < 21 Android version, it flickers when animated.

This flickers / blinks on Android < 21.

```
<path
    android:name="v"
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M 116 29 A 44,43,0,1,0,116,115 A 44,43,0,1,0,116,29 Z"
    />
```

This goes fine (doesn't have a elliptical arc "A" sign) on all Android versions, with the same animation:

```
<path
  android:name="v"
  android:fillColor="#000000"
  android:pathData="M 165.857 147.399 L 186.099 148.062 L 193.305 331.468 L 173.062 330.805 Z" />
```

Animation = rotate.

What could be the problem? Does it have something to do with rendering speed of elliptical arcs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LeBeau explained it is the rendering of the Archs that is slow.

I fixed it by using a different vector image on Android < 21. Here I changed all archs to 20-point polygon's and the rendering is perfect now. You can hardly see the difference: it's a circle to the human eye. No more flickering!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. Android Path class doesn't have an elliptical arc method that exactly matches the behaviour of the SVG one. So SVG arcs have to be converted to one or more beziers.

I don't know for sure whether that's the cause of your problem though.  It will also depend on what sort of animation you are doing.  I wouldn't have thought that a simple rotation would result in the Path being rebuilt.